# Create a pull request to a tag

Tags: github, pull-requests

If there is tag 1.1 for master branch in github, I want to create a pull request with some commits that only apply to that very tag. Is this possible?

Comment: see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go) and [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not provide customer support for GitHub or any other product. This site is about software development concepts, as explained in our [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tag is a named reference to a commit that cannot be moved (without deleting and re-tagging). A branch is a reference to a commit that can be moved forward to track development. So while you can make a local branch off a tagged commit, you can't push a commit to a tag--you have to make a PR to merge into another *branch*.

You could create a branch in your remote named something like `1.1-backfix` off the `1.1` tag, and create a PR to merge into `1.1-backfix`. You could delete and re-tag the new commit as `1.1` (although I wouldn't recommend it). You should probably tag the merge commit as `1.1.1` or some distinct version number when it's released so it can be distinguished from `1.1`

Comment: Both tags and branches are just labels attached to a commit. The difference is that tags are used to refer to a specific version and are expected to never change, whereas branches are floating labels that always point to the most recent commit of a development effort. The only way to move a tag is to delete and then re-create it, and should only be done if a tag was created mistakenly. It is quite sensible that GitHub only allows PRs on branches.

Comment: By the way, I really enjoy your answers here on Software Engineering :)

Comment: Cheers mate! I've updated my answer using some of your better explanation.